# Open Source Licenses, which one?

Tags: java, open-source, licensing

recently I created a java class " Custom Layout Manager ", which I want to make it open-source and distribute it. So it's not really a "product", nor a "complete program".

Here's the list of permissions and specifications:

- You are free to use and modify with some limitations (packages and classes names, should remain the same, if you want another name, extend this class. - The .jar file, project name is ok to change).
- You don't need to share your modifications.
- You can't modify and then sell it to others.
- You can use it as part of your commercial software
  (For example:
  **It's OK if**: you created an instant messaging program, that uses my "Layout", since your "core bussiness" isn't the "Layout", but the msg program.
  **It's NOT OK if**: you created another "Layout" by extending it, added some features and sell it.)
- You can't remove the author's name nor the author's website address.
- You are free to donate. :D

Basically, it's free and it's Ok as you give me credits and don't make money with it.
I guess it might be a little bit complex, since you use it "commercially" but cannot sell it separately.

I have seeked almost all the licenses, and the closest one was MIT license, but it says that you can sell it, so I don't really want to use this one.

Is there any license that fits all these permissions I stated?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several that may fit your needs, but recall the standard "I am not a lawyer" disclaimer.

The two that seem most likely to satisfy your goals are BSD or MIT.  Remember that you always retain the copyright of your code.  These licenses give freedom for someone to incorporate your work with credit, but you do not lose your rights.  Most companies I have worked with are okay using licenses such as these, but will stay away from GPL for intellectual property concerns.

There are many out there...  I usually prefer to hold to the more common ones since they generally meet my needs.  Here is a good resources to read about some of the specific differences:  http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical (it can get kind of dry).

It is also important to distinguish between "free" software and "open source" software.  The semantics of which cause religious battles.  There is a good article on the difference here: http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. About the MIT license, it says: Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software [.....] including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or <b>sell copies of the Software</b> .. [..] I'm afraid that this is the only permission I don't want to let go. and about the BSD license, nothing was said about selling. So I'm still unsure about which to choose. I might use BSD after all...

Comment: Yeah, MIT is about as close to "do whatever you want this this" as it gets.  Just to make sure, are you trying to keep someone from selling your code directly, or from selling an application that utilizes it?

Comment: I'm trying to keep someone from selling my code directly. They can sell it or do whatever they want if they just utilizes it.

Comment: Hmmm...  Assuming someone just took your code alone and posted it "for sale", I believe you are covered under copyright law.  Someone would be crazy to pay for it, since you are providing it free anyway.  If they are selling code as part of a larger application that happened to include yours, you would have a hard time claiming any damages with any open source license.

Comment: I see, one of the main reasons I don't want to let them just modify and sell it, because, I'm pretty sure there are people who are able of making it a thousand times more powerful or useful, but then, they end up selling it. What I wish is that it can be just as programming languages, you don't really see people modifying a language and then sell it. This sort of "principle" is what I'd like to keep with my codes/projects. Well, I guess I'll choose BSD and then hope that the powerful version keeps free. :D. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Best of luck to you...  Open source can be a bit frightening, but at least you will retain accreditation for your work (assuming people aren't evil).